# Adding line numbers when parsing many CSV files with Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently having Spark parse a large number of small CSV-files into one large dataframe. Something along the lines of

```py
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("file*.csv")
```

Because of how the data set being parsed is structured I need the *line* numbers *within the corresponding source CSV-file* of every row in `df`. Is there some simple way of achieving this (preferably without resorting to reconstructing them afterward by a combination of grouping on `input_file_name()` and `zipwithindex()`)?

For example if

```
# file1.csv
col1, col2
A, B
C, D
```

and

```
# file2.csv
col1, col2
E, F
G, H
```

I need a resulting data frame equivalent to

```
row, col1, col2
1, A, B
2, C, D
1, E, F
2, G, H
```

Comment: Is that python? Is there any way you can load your .csv file names into a list? Like this ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", ..., "filen.csv"]?

Comment: Language is not too important (either Scala or Python would be fine). I guess I could get the filenames using some library for accessing the underlying data source (hdfs).

Answer (score 3):

*If you require any arbitrary order of the row_number in a dataframe, you could use the following alternatives.*

One alternative is to use monotonically_increasing_id function if you are using spark 2.x

Something like this

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("file*.csv").withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

The other alternative would be using `row_number`. But that works if you have partition in the dataframe

Something like

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("file*.csv").withColumn("rowId", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("col1")
```

This will ensure the row number is populated per partition.

However, if you require exact ordering, I am afraid there are no "sparky" way to do it. The reason being once you read data as a dataframe it looses the ordering with which the data was persisted before.

You could merge the csv files using a java program in a single machine and add the row number in the program.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but none of these would give rowIds corresponding to lines in the source csv files. Unless I'm mistaken the first would give an arbitrary sequence of increasing IDs (depending on how the data frame is partitioned) and the latter would give indices increasing within unique values of the first column?

Comment: Oh, you want same order. That would be very hard to do in spark. Once you read data as a dataframe it looses the ordering with which the data was persisted before.

Comment: It is as @AvishekBhattacharya said. It is not possible to generate the rowIds in the same order as they are in each .csv using Spark, since it loads data as non-deterministic partitions. You will have to use Python Pandas, R, Excel or any other tool/language to do that into your .csv files and then load them into Spark. Do you have any column into your data that can be used to order it?

Comment: pre-processing as text file and using filename could work. zipWithIndex.

Comment: Yea, my current plan is to process the contents of each file using pandas or similar. Long term maybe write a patched version of the CSV loader.

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya: Thanks a lot man, I spent many hours to find a solution, finally your suggestion solved the problem by using monotonically_increasing_id

Comment: If the CSV files are on one partition each, won’t the above methods work?